# User location with direction

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit, apple-maps

I want to show the direction on with the current location annotation, according to the user rotation in iOS map. Now I can see a location without direction.

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView! {
    didSet {
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.mapType = .standard
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: A `CLLocation` object has a property called `course`, which is a `CLLocationDirection`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation

Answer (score 0):

You should use CoreLocation to do it

Here is a great tutorial to get the basic idea 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/22/2/requesting-location-core-location

To get a direction you can use property 
    `course`
from CLLocation object